# PHP variable in header redirect dosent work

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to redirect with this code:

```
header("Location: ?pid='".$_GET['pid']."'");
die();
```

When I write a simple `echo $_GET['pid'];` the value is good but then when I introduce this variable in the `header` it return something like 27%27 and thats not true true value

Whats the problem here?

Thank you

Comment: it's  the way you're using the quotes. Remove the single quotes. See the answer below, that's how.

Comment: complete working example posted use url_encode function

Answer (score 2):

You have quotes within quotes. Try this instead:

```
header('location: ?pid='.urlencode($_GET['pid']));
```

The [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function takes care of any reserved characters in the url.

**Description**

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite without single quotes in location, because %27 is html character code for single quote:

```
header("Location: ?pid=".$_GET['pid']);
die();
```